# Cakephp link alert

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following link to a delete function in cake:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__(''), array('action' => 'delete', $website['Website']['website_id']), array('class' => 'icon-trash   '), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $website['Website']['website_id'])); ?>
```

Now as you can see there should be a message saying: `Are you sure you want to delete?`

But when i click the link nothing happens (exepect from my field being deleted ofcourse :P )

So how can i make the link display a confirmation box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array(
    'action' => 'delete', $website['Website']['website_id']), array(
    'class' => 'icon-trash'
   ), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $website['Website']['website_id'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code in below structure,

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $website['Website']['website_id']),
    array(),
    "Are you sure you wish to delete this recipe?"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of this, you're now passing five arguments.

Remove the `null` and it should work;

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    // title
    __('delete'),
    // URL
    array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'delete', $document['id']),
// Options
array('escape' => false),

// confirmMessage
__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $document['file'])
```

);
See the documentation; [FormHelper::postLink()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3apostLink)

hope this will sure help you.